# Where to set environment variable in Azure Data Studio Python Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, azure-data-studio

I started using Azure Data studio Notebook, I am having some credentials in environment variables. How can I use those environment variables in Azure Data studio?

Answer (score 0):

For now I've added the .env loader at first step

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv("dev_environment")
```

Answer (score 0):

## Use azure key vault:

Install the library from notebook :

```bash
!pip install azure-keyvault-secrets
```

Sample Usage :

```py
from azure.identity import ManagedIdentityCredential
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient

credential = ManagedIdentityCredential()
client = SecretClient(vault_url="key_vault_url", credential=credential)
secret = client.get_secret("Key_Name")
secret_value = secret.value
```